# Accidentally placed lists inside of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

When I run this file, everything seems to calculate correctly, except for the fact that I end up with the individual list elements inside of lists themselves. This makes it difficult to do some other operations I would like to perform on the individual parts of the list.

My code:

```
growthslist = []
f = open("growths.txt",'r')
count = 0
for line in f:
    count+=1
charnum = int((count/9))
f.seek(0)
for i in range(count):
    growthslist.append(f.readline().splitlines())
namelist = []
namecounter = 0
for i in range(charnum):
    namelist.append(growthslist[namecounter])
    namecounter +=9
print(namelist)
```

When I run this code, it returns [['Test 1'], ['Test 2'], ['Test 3'], ['Test 4'], ['Test 5']].
Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Remove `.splitlines()`.

Comment: You might find [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) useful in your code.  .... ```for count, line in enumerate(f): ... ```

Answer (score 3):

This part:

```
growthslist.append(f.readline().splitlines())
```

Is your problem. `str.splitlines()` returns a list. That's why you're seeing a list of lists, rather than a flat list. But you don't need `str.splitlines()` anyway since you're already using `file.readline()`. Just use that:

```
growthslist.append(f.readline())
```

If you have extra whitespace you need to strip from the lines, use `str.strip()`:

```
growthslist.append(f.readline().strip())
```

As noted in the comments by @idjaw, an alternately way to accomplish your goal would be to read the contents of the file, *then*  use `splitlines()` to separate each line removing any trailing whitespace:

```
f.read().splitlines()
```

Also, consider using the [context manager statement `with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). It will ensure that your files will always be closed regardless of any errors or issues that arise during program execution.

Comment: That's weird, though, since when I use only f.readline, I get EOL characters. This is my output: `['Test1\n', 'Test2\n', 'Test3\n', 'Test4\n', 'Test5\n']`

Comment: @Absolutely-disgusting I see. If you have extra whitespace, than use `str.strip()` to remove it. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: @Absolutely-disgusting Glad I could help out :)

Comment: Alternatively, I *think* you can then do `f.read().splitlines()`. Need to test that though.

Comment: @idjaw I just tested and I believe you're right. Thanks. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`f.readline()` returns one line. No reason to split it. `.splitlines()` turns it into a list.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
f = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
```